# unexpected T_VARIABLE on opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I'm getting this error on an open cart library file:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /public_html/system/library/session.php on line 12
```

been trying to find it's source, but I can't track it down, nothing shows up in error logs about it. The file came with opencart installation, was never edited or anything like that.
Also, there are no *vqmods*, modules, extensions or anything that modifies the session.php file in any way...

Here's the file causing the error, on the IF ending bracket:

```
<?php
class Session {
public $data = array();

public function __construct() {
    if (!session_id()) {
        ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'On');
        ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');

        session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
        session_start();
    }

    $this->data =& $_SESSION;
}

function getId() {
    return session_id();
}
}
?>
```

Any light is appreciated here, thank you !

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the PHP code you've pasted

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I was just about to edit this question by saying that the server hosting that site is not one of the best ones around... 
Had some troubles installing SSL on it and for some reason, the site on HTTPS has a cache that can remain there for DAYS unchanged... maybe I could actually be facing a server problem and not a code one here ?

Comment: It does sound reasonable to blame the server, yes, as there is no problem in the code to yield the error you've given.

Comment: All I can suggest is reuploading the file. They can get corrupted sometimes... (assuming this is not a copy-paste of the actual live file)

Comment: It actually is a copy/paste, that's an Opencart system file, comes as it is, didn't changed anything in there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, @hd and @rjdown, it was actually a server problem really.
I filed a ticket on their help-desk and they told me they were restructuring their servers, hiring new people... and someone in there screwed up my SSL :P

Thanks !